# reformatting a json file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a large json file with the data organized vertically like this

```
{
  "id": "blah",
  "jurisdiction": "ny",
  "name": "blah blah"
},
{
  "id": "blah",
  "jurisdiction": "ny",
  "name": "blah blha blah"
},
{
  "id": "blah",
  "jurisdiction": "ny",
  "name": "blahblah"
},
```

If I try to run a rake task with that data like this

```
task :import => :environment do     

      File.open(File.join(Rails.root, "lib", "tasks", "entries.json"), "r") do |file|
      file.each do |line|   
      entry_attrs = JSON.parse(line) if line && line.length >= 2
      Court.create!(entry_attrs)

    end
  end

end
```

I get an unexpected token error

```
757: unexpected token at '{
```

If I manually change the json into a horizontal line

```
{ "id": "blah", "jurisdiction": "ny", "name": "blah blah"}
```

Then the import works. Is there a way to write the rake task so that it can deal with the json organized in a vertical fashion or is there a way to programmatically change the json file into the proper format?

Update

I put it all together in a string like this. When I ran the rake import it printed all the json to the screen, with the very last entry followed by a comma

```
  {
      "Id": "blah",
      "jurisdiction": "ny",
      "name": "blah blah"
    }
'
```

after which there was an exception in parse

```
l/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.0/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
```

Therefore, the rake task never got to the second loop in which I do `Court.create!(court)`. I'm not sure if it's the trailing comma that's the problem.

```
task :import => :environment do 

    File.open(File.join(Rails.root, "lib", "tasks", "file.json"), "r") do |file|
    string = ''
    file.each do |line|      
     string += line     
    end
    court_attrs = JSON.parse(string) if string  
    court_attrs.each do |court|
     Court.create!(court)
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

You have several problems, not least of which is that JSON doesn't allow trailing commas. In addition, multiple objects ought to be nested inside an array. However, if you have *valid* JSON objects, it's easy to wrap them into a string for parsing using interpolation.

### Wrap JSON Objects in String

You need to convert your JSON data into an array of objects. The easiest way to do this is to wrap the objects in an array literal, and then return the entire array as a string for parsing by [JSON#parse](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse).

```
require 'json'

# Use StringIO to simulate your file on disk.
file = StringIO.new %q/
{
  "id": "blah",
  "jurisdiction": "ny",
  "name": "blah blah"
},
{
  "id": "blah",
  "jurisdiction": "ny",
  "name": "blah blha blah"
},
{
  "id": "blah",
  "jurisdiction": "ny",
  "name": "blahblah"
}
/

# Convert file contents to a string
# containing an array of objects.
json = JSON.parse "[#{file.read}]"
```

This will return an array of hashes, which is a valid Ruby data structure. For example, the above will yield:

```
[{"id"=>"blah", "jurisdiction"=>"ny", "name"=>"blah blah"},
 {"id"=>"blah", "jurisdiction"=>"ny", "name"=>"blah blha blah"},
 {"id"=>"blah", "jurisdiction"=>"ny", "name"=>"blahblah"}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So is your point about 'valid Ruby data structure' as simple as my original json file not being one of the types listed here? hence the need to put it in an array? http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Data_types

Comment: The array is a requirement of the JSON format. Your JSON file contains a series of unnamed elements. That's an array. You express that in JSON by putting commas between them and enclosing the whole thing in square brackets.

Comment: @edPlunkett ok, thanks so why does it have to be converted to a string if an array is a valid Ruby data type

Comment: JSON is a text format for storing and transmitting structured information. The JSON text you are reading out of the file is a string to begin with. You are converting it FROM a string. Say you have a Ruby program on a server, that needs to send some data structures to a client on another continent. It converts Ruby data structures to a JSON-formatted string, which can be sent over HTTP. It does so. The client parses the string to re-create the original data structures. That's what JSON is for. What you're doing is essentially the client end of that scenario.

Comment: Thanks so much for clarifying.It didn't occur to me that the data in the json file was a string since file ends in `.json` and contents not wrapped in `''`.

Comment: @Leahcim JSON is a data interchange format, not a native Ruby data type. See http://www.json.org/ for ways to construct valid JSON structures. In particular, note the difference between an *object* and an *array* in JSON.

Comment: @Leahcim Yeah, like XML or HTML or PostScript: Until your code parses it somehow and converts it into runtime data structures, it's just a stream of zeroes and ones that happen to correspond to ASCII characters. Binary files aren't just magically freeze-dried language-native data structures, either, but they usually look a lot less readable in vi.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're parsing each line separately. "{" isn't a complete valid JSON string. Try concatenating all the lines together into one big string and parse the whole thing at once.

Comment: I tried your solution but it threw an error. If you have time can you please look at the update in the OP and suggest how i might fix it.